# Behavior of multiple flat coils in a cylinder

Tags: electromagnetism

I am trying to wrap my head around how this would work.

The setup is quite simple - there are multiple flat coils sealed in insulated disks, and an active coil with alternating current underneath. All is placed in a cylinder.

The question is, how will the disks behave - all should induce the same magnetic field and thus repel each other. Will this force be stable enough, when the field collapses on each pulse?

Thanks!